# Android - Unable to login in google plus from app showing An internal error occured

Tags: android, google-plus

In my app user can login to google plus using **GoogleApiClient**. In Google developer console website i entered sha1 fingerprint, package in credentials tab and entered email address and product name in consent screen tab.

For debugging i created SHA1 fingerprint using keytool in my local machine and i tried to login its working. For releasing app, i'm exporting apk and installed in phone. In this release app i'm creating sha1 fingerprint programmatically but i'm not able to login using google plus. Its showing "An internal error occured".

**Error:**

`ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{427078b8: android.os.BinderProxy@426e21a0}}`

How to create `sha1` fingerprint for release apk? Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Kamal

Comment: just a suggestion did you setup consent screen over the console?

Comment: Yes i added email address and product name in consent screen

Comment: `How to create sha1 fingerprint for release apk? Please help me to solve this issue.` its simple just open the console and replace debug.keystore with your keystore file and use alias that you entered while signing the apk!

Comment: I solved this issue. while exporting eclipse shows the certificate fingerprint. I used that sha1 fingerprint in developer goolge plus console. Its working fine for debug and release apk. Thanks a lot.